# Custom countdown timer class to replace the Android CountdownTimer

Tags: java, multithreading, android, timer

This project was made to replace the stock Android `CountdownTimer` class. It is more responsive when completing the timer and adds additional functionality such as lap counting and start, pause, resume, and stop methods.

However, I am not so familiar with threads and was wondering if I am doing it right and how it can be improved.

I will post the `MainActivity` where the timer is being used as well as my `CustomTimer` class.

**CustomTimer.java**

```
package CustomTimer;

import android.app.Activity;

/**
 * Created by moshe on 5/12/2016.
 */
public class CustomTimer extends Thread {

    public interface TimerListener{
        public void newLap(int lapNumber);
        public void onTick(long timeRemainingMillis);
    }

    private TimerListener listener;
    private Activity activity;

    private long timerStartMillis;
    private long timeRemainingMillis;
    private long lapLengthMillis;
    private int  lapNumber;
    private long previousTickMillis;
    private long tickLength;
    private long timePaused;

    private boolean clockRunning;
    private boolean clockBegan;

    public CustomTimer(Activity activity) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        lapLengthMillis = 0;
        timerStartMillis = 0;
        lapNumber = 0;
        timeRemainingMillis = 0;
        previousTickMillis = 0;
    }

    public void setListener(TimerListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void setLapLengthMillis(long lapLengthMillis){
        this.lapLengthMillis = lapLengthMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while(true) {
            while (clockBegan) {
                if (clockRunning) {
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timeRemainingMillis = (timerStartMillis + lapLengthMillis * (lapNumber + 1)) - currentTime;

                    if (currentTime - previousTickMillis >= tickLength) {
                        previousTickMillis = currentTime;
                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                listener.onTick(timeRemainingMillis);
                            }
                        });
                        //Log.d("Tick happening", "" + timeRemainingMillis);
                    }
                    if (timeRemainingMillis < 0) {
                        lapNumber++;
                        timeRemainingMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                listener.newLap(lapNumber);
                            }
                        });
                        //Log.d("New lap happening", ""+lapNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setTickLength(long tickLength) {
        this.tickLength = tickLength;
    }

    public boolean isClockRunning(){
        return clockRunning;
    }

    public void stopClock() {
        clockBegan = false;
        clockRunning = false;
    }
    public void pauseClock(){
        clockRunning = false;
        timePaused = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void startClock(){
        if(!clockBegan) {
            timerStartMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            previousTickMillis = timerStartMillis;
            lapNumber = 0;
            clockRunning = true;
            clockBegan = true;
            if(State.NEW == this.getState())
                super.start();
        }else{
            resumeClock();
        }
    }

    public  void resumeClock(){
        clockRunning = true;
        timerStartMillis += (System.currentTimeMillis() - timePaused);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.itnstudios.customtimer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import CustomTimer.CustomTimer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomTimer timer;
    TextView tvClock;
    Button startButton, pauseButton, resumeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
        resumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_resume);

        tvClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_clock);
        updateClock(5000);

        timer = new CustomTimer(this);
        timer.setLapLengthMillis(5000);
        timer.setTickLength(500);
        timer.setListener(new CustomTimer.TimerListener() {
            @Override
            public void newLap(int lapNumber) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lap Number: " + lapNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long timeRemainingMillis) {
                updateClock(timeRemainingMillis);
                Log.d("Tick Happening", timeRemainingMillis+"");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void updateClock(long timeInMillis) {
        int min = (int) (timeInMillis / 60000);
        int sec = (int) ((timeInMillis % 60000) / 1000);
        tvClock.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", min, sec));
    }

    public void startClock(View v){
        timer.startClock();
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void pauseClock(View v){
        timer.pauseClock();
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resumeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void resumeClock(View v){
        timer.resumeClock();
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void stopClock(View v){
        timer.stopClock();
        resumeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So you're not exactly thread safe.  Even though you're extending `Thread`, that does not mean that its own methods will be called within it's ownership.  For example, if you had a super simple class like this:

```
public class TestThread extends Thread {
    public void test(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ":" + getId());
    }
}
```

and instantiate and call it from somewhere else:

```
new TestThread().test();
```

you'll see that it's probably not going to match.

Thread "safety" can be very complicated.  One major consideration is "memory consistency", where each thread might make a cache copy of information you have in memory, and so might write to them at different times.  Often this isn't even noticeable, but if the order or state of a variable matters, it can get tricky.  This might apply to you since you're updating a lot of variables, inherently between processes.

I'd spend some time reading up on thread safety in Java (there are a ton of resources online, all of them will do a better job explaining than I have), and I probably wouldn't *extend* `Thread` here - I think most people would probably use a `Thread` but the class itself would not be a subclass.